# SQL Views. How to calculate row's value based on previous&current row comparison

Tags: sql

There's a sql table
[image]

so, pattern is that the last column contains levels that drop to some number and then jump back to a higher value
Is there a way to create a SQL view that contains a SignalColumn like on the picture below?
[image]

Here the SignalColumn Total gives you the number of jumps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(cntinktonerblack) over (partition by cntqueue order by cntdate) > cntinktonerblack
             then 1 else 0
        end) as signalcolumn
from t;
```

If you want a view, use `create view as` with this query.

Comment: It works! Your answer is very much appreciated!!